# Calculating difference (or deltas) between current and previous row with clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

*It would be awesome if there was a way to index rows during a query.*

Is there a way to SELECT (compute) the difference of a single column between consecutive rows?

Let's say, something like the following query

```
SELECT 
  toStartOfDay(stamp) AS day,  
  count(day )  AS  events ,
  day[current] - day[previous] AS difference, -- how do I calculate this
  day[current] / day[previous] as percent, -- and this
FROM  records
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY day
```

I want to get the integer and percentage difference between the current row's 'events' column and the previous one for something similar to this:

| day | events | difference | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | 197 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | 656 | 459 | 3.32 |
| 2022-01-08 00:00:00 | 15 | -641 | 0.02 |
| 2022-01-09 00:00:00 | 7 | -8 | 0.46 |
| 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 137 | 130 | 19.5 |

Comment: How do you get -451 from 15? Are there issues in your expected output?

Comment: For some other `DBMS`s you can use `LAG()` function to get the previous values of a row value, for `clickhouse` you may workaround. check https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/

Answer (score 2):

My version of Clickhouse doesn't support window-function but, on looking about the LAG() function mentioned in the comments, I found **neighbor()**, which works perfectly for what I'm trying to do

```
SELECT 
  toStartOfDay(stamp) AS day,  
  count(day )  AS  events ,
  (events - neighbor(events, -1)) as diff,
  (events / neighbor(events, -1)) as perc
FROM  records
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY day
```